# Is there a way to display items from an array on separate lines of a TextBox?

Tags: c#

I have added the items from a checkbox into listbox named `displayBurgerBox` then into an array.  Now I want to display each order (array) on a separate line of a textbox when i click a button.  I am getting this text in the box instead of the order `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+ObjectCollection`. Any ideas, or should I use a different approach.

```
private void addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] listOfItems = new string[1000];
    int numberOfItems = 0;

    listOfItems[numberOfItems] = Convert.ToString(displayBurgerBox.Items);

    orderList.AppendText(listOfItems[numberOfItems]);
    orderList.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show(listOfItems[numberOfItems]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues lies in following line.

```
Convert.ToString(displayBurgerBox.Items);
```

Instead you should

```
displayBurgerBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray()
```

Additionally I would suggest you not to declare array of fixed size up front, rather use

```
var listOfItems= displayBurgerBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray()
```

Finally, you can concat array using

```
string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}",listOfItems)
```

Your final code as in the example you have shared would look like.

```
private void addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var listOfItems = displayBurgerBox.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}",listOfItems));
        textBox1.Text = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", listOfItems);
 }
```

PS : You had mentioned you wanted to add it to textbox, but couldn't find a code which reflect the same. Have added code to add to textbox now. Please do remember to change TextBox's MultiLine Property to true to view multiple lines

Comment: @RickySinclair in above scenario, you dont need to, listOfItems is a variable local to the function, and each time you click the button, it would be recreated by converting list items. each recreated instance would have a size is befitting the source list items.